# Matplotlib zoom in/out feature in Jupyer notebook without installing packages

Tags: matplotlib

please I'm working from my office and I have here Anaconda installed on my machine. I have different dataframes that I plot using matplotlib (see example below). I would need the ability to zoom in/out with the mouse without installing gtk or plotly or any additional library.
Is there any simple way to add this feature?
Many thanks

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.DataFrame(randn(50,4),columns='W X Y Z'.split())
df["X"].plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: The `%matplotlib inline` backend produces png images. You cannot zoom into images. You may use the `%matplotlib notebook` backend instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `%maptlotlib inline` with `%matplotlib notebook`.

Now you have an interactive figure in your notebook.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!!!! you can't imagine how much time I spent trying to find this simple solution. Thank you